# How do I import PEAK's PCAN-Basic dll functions into my java program?

Tags: java, dll, import, java-native-interface

I am currently making a program that will interface CAN device using the [PCAN-Basic API](https://www.peak-system.com/PCAN-Basic.239.0.html?&L=1). I am working in Eclipse Oxygen and have included both PCANBasic.dll and PCANBasi_JNI.dll in my build path libraries, I have even followed these [instructions](https://www.peak-system.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=870&hilit=SysWow64) from the developers, but with no consequence.

I am pretty well versed in Java, but have never really worked with native interfaces like this and I cannot seem to import the API correctly.

Here is my existing code:

```
package application;

import peak.can.basic.*;

public class CanInterface {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("PCANBasic_JNI");
    }

    public CanInterface() {
        PCANBasic can = new PCANBasic();
        can.initializeAPI();
    }
}
```

I get these basic errors:

Line 3: `The import peak cannot be resolved.`

Line 11: `PCANBasic cannot be resolves to a type.`

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if I can give you anything else.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up solving my own problem. Long story short, had top fix some issues with where Eclipse was trying to reference resources.

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail how you solved this?

Comment: Eclipse was looking for my Resource directory in a different place than expected, I simply had to change the referenced directory. I also could've just moved the files.